# Get page jump link (#, internal anchor) from Wordpress URL

Tags: php, wordpress, url, hash

I have got a link on **page1** which is

```
www.abc.de/page2/#link1
```

(also tried `www.abc.de/page2#link1`)

On **page2** I'd like to read the page jump portion **link1**.

I tried `get_query_var()` and all the other URL-bound functions but no result. I just can get the page name **page1** from the referer.

Is there way to get the link portion in php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible with [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/function.parse-url.php), see example:

```
var_dump(parse_url("www.abc.de/page2/#link1", PHP_URL_FRAGMENT));
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work with Wordpress. parse_url() is ok but he last url part (the fragment) is not visible. The url "ends with /page2" in Wordpress it seems.

Comment: Wordpress is only CMS. It shouldn't affect PHP functions. Are you shure that your first parameter is valid url with hash fragment? Could you display that url with `var_dump` before you use `parse_url`?